# Android, HttpPost working with ip, not with url

Tags: android, http-post

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://simonexxx.no-ip.info/ilMercatinoDelxxx/ModificaArticolo?id=" + id);
//HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://151.xx.xx.247:8080/ilMercatinoDelxxx/ModificaArticolo?id=" + id);
```

Is there any possible reason why the HttpPost works perfectly with the IP (commented line) but not writing the relative url?

I can acces the resource with the browser in both ways.
Obviously the xxx are just for privacy.

I get:

> Sending signal. PID: 15236 SIG: 3
>  threadid=3: reacting to signal
>   3
>  Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

This log should simply say I'm accessing internet from the UI activity, that should not be done, ok. But writing the IP it works fine.

Comment: is simonexxx.no-ip.info pointing to localhost?

Comment: yes, is a dynanic dns, my pc is the "server"

Comment: android emulator and the server is working on the same machine then?

Comment: No I'm debugging directly on my Galaxy Nexus

Comment: could u try using emulator with solution i just posted below?

Comment: No sorry, I did a mistake, simonexxx.no-ip.info is pointing to my public IP : 8080, where tomcat is listening

Comment: in this case url should be http://simonexxx.no-ip.info:8080 right? ;)  with port appended at the end. dns mapping ip-domain is cleaner than fwding

Comment: no, entering simonexxx.no-ip.info in my browser, the request goes to a dynamic dns that translate that url in http://151.xx.xx.247:8080/ , that is my public IP. The port forwarding is added in translation by no.ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with port. Usually DNS names translate to IP addresses and keeping the default port (80), unless you have defined to forward your request to a specific port in DNS records. Now in case of no-ip, it seems like you are using a free account and there is no such feature (in free accounts) to define port together with IP address to offer DNS name.

So in your case, you need to append port number together with your address, as mentioned by @Martin Maurer

Comment: In no-ip I setted an automatic forward to port 8080. Infact I can acces  http://simonexxx.no-ip.info/ilMercatinoDelxxx/ModificaArticolo?id with my browser rigth now

Comment: can you access that url in browser and see the results? for e.g. using jquery

Comment: or, log on the server to check if your webserver really receives a request from your phone

Comment: I does not recive the request.

Comment: so, it means your dns is not forwarding to port 8080

Comment: if you recently set the port in no-ip then wait for some time before testing, because it may take some time for the changes to take effect

Comment: I set it days ago. I'll try to remove automatic port forwarding and add :8080 by myself

Comment: yes, do that... I remember i also used to have same issue when setting up my ftp server and eventually i had to start entering port number manually in the url

Comment: OK in no-ip configuration I swapped from "Port 80 Redirect : 8080" to "DNS Host (A)" and added :8080 in the HttpPost. Now HttpPost("http://simonexxx.no-ip.info:8080/ilMercatinoDelxxx/ModificaArticolo?id=" + id); works fine =) Thank you

Comment: The problem is that now everyone can enter in my router =(

Comment: free service comes with drawbacks too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following line:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://simonexxx.no-ip.info:8080/ilMercatinoDelxxx/ModificaArticolo?id=" + id);
```

Comment: same result, btw the port 8080 is added automatically by no-ip

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem comes from; android emulator cannot access localhost.
solution is simple though.

instead of using http://localhost:...
you should use http://10.0.2.2:....
that enables the emulator to resolve and make call to any service running on localhost

Comment: Yes but I need to contact the servlet using a public IP, not from inside my net